# What is equivalent of VB6.0's MaskColor property in C#

Tags: c#, vb6, background-color, masking

The `MaskColor` property in VB 6.0 is used to remove the background color of an `Image`. How might I do the same in C#?

Comment: Link to VB6 docs, for completeness. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239018(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can use [MakeTransparent(Color color)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8517ckds%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the bitmap image. example:

```
//convert the red color in the image into transparent.
((Bitmap)BackgroundImage).MakeTransparent(Color.Red);
```

Comment: I thought that required the bottom left pixel to be the color you were targeting.  I love it when I learn new stuff around here!

Comment: @Dev You are welcome, don't forget to mark this answer as [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it answers your question right, so others will know how your problem actually solved

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any direct equivalent.

I've made it work in the past by using the ColorMap class to map my background color to Color.Transparent.  Then I create an ImageAttributes object and call the SetRemapTable() function and pass it my ColorMap.  Then you redraw the image by passing the ImageAttributes to the DrawImage method.

Edit:

Jalal posted a much easier way for a solid color.  I took a closer look at the code where I was using the method above, I was mapping more than one shade of the same base color to transparent.

Comment: Wow, this is a very long turn ;)

Comment: It's been a few years, but I remembered doing this and still have the code.  Turns out I was mapping more than one shade of a color to transparent.  Your way is clearly superior for a single solid color.

Comment: +1, this is useful though, I don't know about the performance here but you can call `MakeTrasparent` method multiple times for each color you want to make transparent in the same bitmap

Comment: It would be interesting to see what MakeTransparent is doing.  I may look into that when I'm more awake tomorrow :)