# Button Text not visible with background image

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a situation where I am applying an image to a button, however due to the colour of the image, the text of the button is not always visible. I cannot just change the button text colour due to not knowing what colour the button image will be (this is up to the customer) and I have ran out of ideas to try! The best idea i had was to apply a 'Stroke' to the text (with a colour opposite the text colour itself) so therefore even if the text colour itself is not visible the stroke will be however I have not being able to find any relevant examples of how to do this. Is this the best solution the problem? If so could anyone provide an example of how to do this? Or recommend a better solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the usage of MaskColor property already?

Comment: I did not, i will look into this now! Thank you very much

Comment: `MaskColor ` There is not such thing in C# winforms. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129956/what-is-equivalent-of-vb6-0s-maskcolor-property-in-c-sharp)

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7462/Dynamically-Write-Text-On-An-Image how to write dynamically text on an image

Comment: Sorry very silly of me not to add this initially - The background is not always one solid colour which I would imagine makes this more difficult. Is there a way i could set say 2/3 pixels around the text to transparent in order to make it more visible?

Comment: Which background are you talking here about? The Image?

Comment: The image is the background for my button and of course the text is on top of this, the problem is the text is hard to read with images of certain colours.

Comment: @TaW Sorry I remembered it wrong because I use Infragisctics components which allow using it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have got one of two good solutions right in your question.

To create a 'stroke' or 'shadow' you will have to paint the button by yourself.

Not easy, usually, because of the visual styles the user may have active on his machine..

If your image fills the button anyway, you may get away with rather few lines of code, though..

Here is a little example to get you started:

```
private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  // the background image
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(button1.BackgroundImage, Point.Empty);
  // maybe a few borderlines ?
  using (Pen penbright = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(155,255,255,255)))
       e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penbright, button1.ClientRectangle);
  using (Pen pendark = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(155, 0, 0, 0)))
       e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pendark, 
                                new Rectangle(new Point(-1,-1), button1.ClientSize));
  // Now the Text: Stroke: white over black 
  e.Graphics.DrawString(button1.Text, button1.Font, Brushes.Black, new Point(10,10));
  e.Graphics.DrawString(button1.Text, button1.Font, Brushes.White, new Point(11,11));
}
```

to be improved:

- The positions for the DrawStrings should be adapted
- If the Image doesn't cover the whole button text we'll will have to refine the code a little..

Note that there is no visual feedback during the button press..

The other solution may be to change the Images.

Can you post one or two example images?

Comment: Unfortunatly due to my reputation i am unable to post images. I am going to give this a go and if this fails i am going to attempt to draw the text onto the image itself. Thank you very much for the assistance though!

Comment: OK. BTW, there many free places where new user can post images, like [TinyPic](http://tinypic.com/); even with no reps you can still post the urls..

Comment: Oh of course, sorry i did not think of that. I'll keep that in mind for future reference.